# BeautifulSoup4: How can I extract tags by class but ignore all attributes that follow after

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a span tag with the class "balancedHeadline". If I specify the class like I have below it returns an empty list. If I remove the class specification it returns all spans, which includes information I do not want. I believe it is because there are attributes following the class attribute but I may be wrong or missing something else. Can anyone help me out here?

For reference I am trying to extract all article headlines from [www.nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, features='html.parser')

articleNames = soup.find_all('span', class_='balancedHeadline')

for i in articleNames:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of html text with the `balancedHeadline` class? Because your code looks ok, and when I request `https://www.nytimes.com` it doesn't contain any examples of this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

You trying to scrape the article name by class name. But When you scrape the website content. you don't get "balancedHeadline" class. beacuse it's not available with a span tag. That's why articalename list is empty.

[See the webiste articale Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoV9V.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/"
payload={}
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'nyt-a=v0-ZAEiGSnGx2kLlO94uOa; nyt-gdpr=0; nyt-geo=IN; nyt- 
   purr=cfhhcfhhhuk'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')
articleNames = soup.find_all('h3', {'class':'css-xxaj7r e1lsht870'})
for i in articleNames:
print(i.span.text)
```

**Output:**

New York Mayor’s Race in Chaos After Board Counts 135,000 Test Ballots

‘We Are Waiting for You’: An Agonizing Vigil for Surfside Families

Security in Afghanistan Is Decaying, U.S. General Says

Delta Variant’s Spread Prompts Reconsideration of Precautions

Jubilant Tigray Capital Greets Insurgents After Ethiopian Retreat

Wisconsin G.O.P. Wrestles With Just How Much to Indulge Trump

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = ' http://www.nytimes.com'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
sections = soup.find_all('section',class_='story-wrapper')
for section in sections:
   heads = section.find_all('h3',class_='css-xxaj7r e1lsht870')
   for head in heads:
      print(head.span.text)

#From the above code i got output as follows without the class name balancedHeadline
    <span>New York Mayor’s Race in Chaos After Board Counts 135,000 Test Ballots</span>
    <span>‘We Are Waiting for You’: An Agonizing Vigil for Surfside Families</span>
```